# Why does Tsuna lose his clothes when infused with the Dying Will?

Tags: reborn

In *Katekyo Hitman Reborn*, whenever Tsuna enters "Dying Will Mode", his clothes tear in half (though he seems to have no shortage of replacements), with the exception of his underpants. This is briefly mentioned on the [*Reborn* Wiki](http://reborn.wikia.com/wiki/Dying_Will_Mode):

> The Dying Will Bullet also has the unusual side-effect of destroying all of the person's clothing except their undergarments.

However, I'm not far into the series and really have no idea why this happens (it bugs me every episode). His muscles don't really expand or anything, the clothes just seem to rip and fly off.

Can anyone shed some light on this, or is this a case of "[Rule of Funny](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)" as a running gag?

Comment: "(it bugs me every episode)" -- don't worry, it's only in the beginning.

Comment: @Xeo Good to know.. I've got well over 180 episodes left. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anime often ignore real world's Physics laws. The losing of clothes on being infused with the Dying Will is used to dramatize the effect it has on Tsuna. It is to make you feel as if Tsuna's body "grows" when he receives the Dying Will, causing his clothes to rip apart.

Also, in a number of cases, receiving the Dying Will causes Tsuna to move from a lying down position to an upright position. This motion may also cause the clothes to rip, since they cannot "keep up" with the Dying Will.

Another explanation is that receiving the Dying Will is so intense that it tears or burns things in his immediate vicinity (which happen to be his clothes). I think this is a case of [Rule of Cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool) in addition to Rule of Funny, and Fanservice could also be another reason.

The underwear remaining intact is for censorship reasons only. See [Magic Pants](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicPants).

Comment: I'm aware that anime often violates physics, though sometimes there is a (plot-related) reason for it. I was wondering if it was the Rule of Cool at play, though I couldn't quite justify running around half-naked in front of your crush as "cool". Good answer though, and that second explanation may be the perfect one (there is a light that shines from his chest or back sometimes, which could be some induction of the intensity). Thanks!

Comment: I like this explanation.  It also fits with later events in the story.

Comment: Wow, that's good to know, because I have only watched till episode 12 so far.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that in the manga he does not only lose his cloths but die's then revive's into a new body. To make the anime more child frendly they just made him fall down and lose his cloths in the process to note the difference from before ( except for the flame on his head). Loseing his cloths also adds to more funny scene's giving some comedian value.

Comment: Yeah, I had heard that in [this question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2365/274), so that whole losing-clothes-thing does seem to be an artifact of the manga as well!