# What happens to the discarded body of a person hit by the Dying Will bullet?

Tags: reborn

In the Reborn manga, being hit with a Dying Will bullet kills you, and you are "reborn" from inside your own body, leaving a carcass behind.  You can see multiple times in the manga that it's not just the clothes that are left behind, but the person's "shed skin" as well.

As far as I remember, nobody ever acknowledged this through the entire run of the series.

**Are the bodies left when a person is hit by the Dying Will bullet ever explained?**

Comment: My guess is that they skipped the carcass/corpse thing in the anime to make it more "children-friendly". I don't have sufficient evidence to back this up. I will post this as an answer when/if I get that evidence.

Comment: I think it's more like a cicada molting.

Comment: Maybe it's something like when snakes shed their skins . Or maybe not. Just a guess. XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no explanation about it anywhere. And I do not think there will be.

The author of the story have left this issue open, to make us think more about it.

From my understanding, the Dying Will bullet shows your inner character (also known as your anima in psychology terms) which reveals his true deeds and his real-self, that is why when Tsuna takes this bullet multiple times, we see him, stronger, more serious, and leader-like figure. Which is his true personality that is hidden underneath his masked personality (the personality that he shows to people when he is not hit by the bullet). Anyway, if you need to go deeper, you might want to read more about [Carl Jung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Jung) and his theories because I think the author of Reborn was influenced by him.

Comment: Do you have any source that Reborn's author was indeed influenced by Carl Jung? Is there any interview or such to prove it?

Comment: I do not, because I do not speak Japanese. but my theory is possible. A lot of authors read about psychology to determine how their characters act especially when they are educated.

Comment: I like this answer.  Unless there's a Q&A with Amano in the future, this is probably as good of an answer as we can get.

Comment: I didn't say that it isn't possible. I'm just asking if there is an interview or something 'cause it'll be interesting. :)

Comment: @xjshiya the ideas of Carl Jung are universal and taught in most of the colleges around the world. I do not think she will say anything about it. because this philosophy is applied pretty much in every anime or manga. She is just focusing a little more about it.